# How to justify double integral evaluating to 0 using symmetry of the multivariable function?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, even-and-odd-functions

Given $f(x,y) = sin(y-2x+1)$ on the rectangular domain $R = [0, 1] \times [-1, 1]$, how is symmetry used to explain why the double integral of $f(x,y)$ over this domain is $0$?

Past attempts I used were "freezing" $x$ or $y$, but I do not understand where to go from there. We are specifically asked to justify why this double integral evaluates to $0$ using symmetry instead of integrating by brute force.

Comment: Line $y-2x+1=0$ is the diagonal of the rectangle $[0,1]\times[-1,1]$, so the symmetry has to be the central symmetry around the centre $(1/2,0)$ of the rectangle. In other words, the diagonal splits the rectangle into two triangles; calculate the integral on one triangle normally and use the substitution $x\mapsto 1-x$, $y\mapsto -y$ for the other.